# Blender rendering: output to unexpected frame numbers

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm correcting some frames in my Cycles render by having them re-rendered correctly and overwriting the originals from frame 135 to frame 144. But when I click animate the render starts at 269 and renders long over the last frame.
Even after I delete the previous incorrect frames and render again and disabling the overwrite option it still starts at frame 269.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you don't have "alternate start/end range" enabled?

Disable it and see if it fixes the issue
[image]